# A Specific Case of Infinitive as Adjective

Tags: adjectives, infinitives, participles, present-participles, infinitive-constructions

*To see him*, you would have supposed he had been doing this for years.

Having first thought that *to see him* was an adverb, I then noticed it wasn’t exactly doing the work of an adverb and might just as well be replaced with the participle *seeing him*, modifying *you*. Is this right, or have I missed something?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't remember seeing a question on this use of a to-infinitival before. Here, 'To see him' looks like a parenthetical. I'd say it's modifying the whole main clause, so many would class it as a sentence adverbial. If it's a pragmatic marker, I'm struggling to classify it. 'Explaining context' seems too closely connected to the matrix sentence's semantics for a true pragmatic marker. It seems like a conditional construction: 'If you evaluated his status from observation alone, ...'.

Comment: Actually, traditional grammar uses the term *gerundial infinitive* for cases where an adjective functions as infinitive. It's not something new. Consider this: _He is a man to honour_. Here the infinitive *to honour* acts as an adjective, modifying *man*.

Comment: Similarly, I think of "To know her is to love her". Perhaps there is an element of conditional parallelism in the statements that helps justify the construction. Regrettably, I doubt that "conditional parallelism" has found its way into the constellation of accepted grammatical concepts.

Comment: It is more correct to say 'The seeing of him would cause one to suppose...'. The infinitive only works in sentences like 'To see him you would need to catch him on his way out.' Or, perhaps, 'to see him is to love him' etc. Causation requires a participle, not an infinitive.

Comment: It is a supplementary adjunct, i.e. it's not a modifier but a supplement located outside clause structure. I'm not sure what kind of subtype of adjunct it is, though there’s a sense in which you could talk of it being a peripheral case of conditional. .